# How can I configure my OpenVPN client config file to route traffic only to the remote LAN?

Tags: openvpn

I have to connect to a VPN for Offensive Security's Proving Grounds, which puts me right in a firewalled, local network environment. While connected to the VPN, I have no access to anything except Proving Ground's internal network. Is there a way I can configure this to only send traffic to `192.168.*.*` through the VPN? Here's the config file I'm working with (default file provided by OffSec):

```
persist-tun
persist-key
tls-client
client
resolv-retry 5
auth-user-pass
connect-retry-max 1
explicit-exit-notify 1
remote-cert-tls server
nobind
remote-random
dev tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
auth SHA1
remote pg-pool1.offseclabs.com 1194 udp
remote pg-pool2.offseclabs.com 1194 udp
verify-x509-name "offensive-security.com" name
#
# CERT STUFFS
#
```

So far, I've tried adding `route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0` to the config, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following lines to my config file:

```
route-nopull
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
```